# How to pass a multi-line string as props in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a string as prop to one of my components. The strings are too long and I need to separated them into different paragraphs (multi-line). I have tried using `\n` but it doesn't seem to work.

Below are the codes.

```
<SimpleCard
            title={"What's our plan?"}
            subtitle={"The end-goal"}
            description={
              "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. \n\n\" +
              "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        }
      />
```

Comment: Send it as jsx element. <p>text1</p><p>text2</p>  [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-cdn-o06of?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript `template literals`. Template literals support multiline string without using any `/n`. It also has some other interesting features also.

The general syntax of `template literals` is to wrap the string inside **``**(back-tick).

An example is given below:

```
<Component
   title={"Title"}
   subtitle={"Subtitle"}
   description={
     `This is the 1st line of the description.
      This is the 2nd line of the description.`
   }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1: Split `\n` and Map

If you prefer writing `\n` in your texts, you can do so with this solution

```
function App(props) {
  return <div>{
    props.text.split("\\n").map(line => (<p>{line}</p>))
  }</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App text="lorem ipsum\nlorem ipsum" />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

### Solution 2: Array of strings

Of course if you want to skip splitting and write out the array that's fine too.

```
function App(props) {
  return <div>{
    props.text.map(line => (<p>{line}</p>))
  }</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App text={['loren ipsum', 'lorem ipsum']} />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```